# Xamarin.Forms log exception when App crashes in Android

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, try-catch

Right now I have a Try Catch in Main.cs for iOS, where I'm logging the exception if the App crashes.

What is the equivalent in Android?

I've seen a lot of posts here and Xamarin Forums about event handlers in MainActivity, but those don't seem to work at all. Example:

```
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException;                
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleExceptions;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
```

I have the methods for each, and they never get called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Exception Handling in Xamarin Cross platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503390/global-exception-handling-in-xamarin-cross-platform)

Comment: consider using appcenter.ms