# Catching EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) exceptions in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, exception, xamarin.ios

I've written my custom exception handler for `Xamarin.Forms` and I noticed that not all exceptions are catched. E.g. this one is not (taken from *Device Logs* in Xcode > Devices and Simulators):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d3d2e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ede288 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000180cabdb0 __abort + 152
...
```

The exception handler is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503390/global-exception-handling-in-xamarin-cross-platform) or [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/28183/#Comment_28183). It uses `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` and `AsyncSynchronizationContext.ExceptionCaught`.

I'm not initializing in `FinishedLaunching()` as in the samples, but I don't think that's the reason for.

Is it possible to catch `EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)` exceptions in `Xamarin.iOS`? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to review the Xamarin.iOS **exception marshaling** using the runtime framework and how the build time flags (`mtouch`) are used to install the handler into app:

#### Example:

```
Runtime.MarshalObjectiveCException += (object sender, MarshalObjectiveCExceptionEventArgs args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Marshaling Objective-C exception");
    Console.WriteLine ("    Exception: {0}", args.Exception);
    Console.WriteLine ("    Mode: {0}", args.ExceptionMode);
};
```

#### Mtouch option:

```
--marshal-objectivec-exceptions=
default
unwindmanagedcode
throwmanagedexception
abort
disable
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/exception-marshaling

Comment: So must I use `--marshal-objectivec-exceptions=throwmanagedexception` as `mtouch` arguments in addition to `Runtime.MarshalObjectiveCException` to catch the `NSException`?

Comment: Now I tried the above option and on compiling I get `Failed to compile the generated code for P/Invoke methods. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com`. Can this code be used in production code or is this only for debugging?