# How to Debug an App Outside of Visual Studio 2019-Pre?

Tags: android, ios, debugging

- I have a cross-platform app that starts and runs fine in the IDE debug mode.
- However, if the app, in a debug compilation, is started from either iOS or Android starts and subsequently fails; it runs fine on UWP though. I have had the app run on them in earlier versions.

**What settings/logs on those OS's should I set to try and debug the executables? 
Is there any documentation for working this type of problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Per this [conversation](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/401130), John suggested "application level unhandled exception handers on each platform" which I researched, found [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503390/global-exception-handling-in-xamarin-cross-platform) here and use it to form my own code to resolve the issue I was having.